# Syntax error on Update statement

Tags: c#, database

What is the correct code for this code I have tried placing [] on all tables and columns and remove the '' on values.

[image: here is my code]

Comment: `String.Format` uses curley braces as placeholders (`{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`).  Also SQL strings need to be single-quoted (and escaped).  It is better to use SQL parameters so that you don't have to remember these things.

Comment: Add your codes as codes not as screen shots that is easy when someone is giving an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to write this query is as below

```
 public bool UpdateMethod(string param1,string param2,string key)
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update [yourTableName]set field1=@param1,field12=@param2 where key=@param3", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", param2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", key);
                return Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
}
```

where con is an object of connection string.

Comment: "cmd" should be wrapped in a "using" statement, to prevent resource leak. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 2):

change the 0, 1, 2, 3 to {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}. also as the comment suggested add quotes around the strings.

Comment: String literals in SQL need to be (safely) quoted as well.

Comment: overall horrible idea to do that. you expose yourself to all kinds of invalid input, including sql injection